# How to store parts of form-data when they're on separate pages?

Tags: html, database, forms, cookies

Whenever I'm to prepare a long form for the client I always want to split it into separate pages, so the visitor doesn't have to fill it all, but does it in steps.

Something like:

```
Step 1  >  Step 2  > Step 3 > Thank You!
```

I've never done it for one reason: I don't know how to store the data from separate steps efficiently? By efficiently I mean, how to store it, so when a visitor decides not to finish it at Step 3 all the data is deleted.

I've come up with few ways of how this could be resolved, but I'm just not convinced by any of them:

1. **Storing form data in database**
   I can imagine a table with columns representing each question, with final column representing a `bool` value whether the form has been completed or not?
   But I would have to do a clean-up of the table every now and then (maybe even every time it gets updated with new data?) and delete all entries with `complete = 0`.
2. **Store form data in session data.**
   This on the other hand, does not have to store data in database (depending on how sessions are being handled) and all info would be in Cookie. But what if browser doesn't support cookies or user disabled them (rare, but happens), or if form has file attachments, then this is a no-go.
3. **`echo`'ing form data from previous page as `<input type="hidden">` on the next page**
   Yes, I'm aware this is a rather stupid idea, but it's an alternative. Poor, but it is.

Option `1` seems to be the best, but I feel it's unnecessary to store temporary data in DB. And what if this becomes a very popular form, with a lot of visitors filling it in? The amount of Updates/Deletes could be massive?

I want to know how you deal with it.

---

**Edit**

David asked a good question. What technology I'm using?
I personally use PHP+MySQL, but I feel like it's more generic question. Please share your solutions no matter of what server-side technology you use, as I'm sure the concept can be adapted one way or the other to different technologies.

Comment: Good question. I know how I would do it in .Net.  I suppose the answer is going to depend onthe server-side technology you use, which is not specified.  (Php, .Net, CGI, some other option?)

Comment: I personally use PHP, but feel free to share .Net solution? Surely it could be somehow adapted to other technologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the choice between options 1 and 2 comes down to how much data you are storing.  I think in most cases the amount of data you are collecting on a form is going to be fairly small (a few kilobytes).  In that case, I think storing it in the session data is the way to go.  There's not that much overhead in passing that amount of data back and forth.  Also, unless your users are on computers where there is a strict security policy in place, the application should work.  If you make the page requirements clear users can decide if they want to proceed or not.

If you are storing large amounts of data for the form then a database would be better so you don't need to pass the data back and forth.  However, I think this is going to be a fairly rare situation.  Even if the application allows the uploading of files you can save those to a temporary location and only write them to the database once the form is completed.  The other situation where you might want to use a database is if your form needs to be able to support the user leaving and coming back at a later time to resume the form.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that option 1 is the best, because it has a few benefits over the other 2:

- If the data is persisted, users can come back later and continue the process
- Your code base will be much cleaner with incremental saves, and it alleviates the need for 1 massive save operation
- Your foot print (each page request) will be lighter than option 3

If you're worried about performance, you can queue the data to be saved, since it's not necessary to save it near-real-time.

Edit to clear up a misconception: The data inside PHP Sessions, by default, are NOT stored in Cookies and are capable of storing a lot of data without too much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with number 2, but use the cookie only for identifying the user. The session data should actually be stored on your server and the cookie merely provides a lookup key to the session object that contains all the details.

If the site becomes popular and needs to run on more than a single web server, then your session data will need to be persisted in some kind of database anyway. In that case you would need a database that could handle massive amounts of transactions.

**Note:** I agree that this is a platform independent question. Stack Overflow users prefer to see code in questions and prefer to give code in answers, so that's why I normally ask what language someone is using.

Answer (score 0):

To be brutally honest, just use the database as in option 1 and stop worring about data volumes.  Seriously if your site is that successful that it becomes a problem then you ought be able fund a re-vamp to cope.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with taking the POST data from the previous step and adding hidden `input` elements. Just take all the POST data from the previous page that you care about and get them into the current page's form. This way, you don't have to worry about using persistent storage in any form, whether it's on the client side or the server side.

What are the perceived downsides? That there are a lot of extra elements on the page? Not that the user sees. All you have to do is add an element for each input you ask the user to give (on every page, if you want the user to be able to go back). Besides these elements, which don't give any visual clutter, there's nothing extra.

There's also the fact that all the form data will have to be transmitted on every page load. Sure, but this is probably going to be faster than a lookup in a database, and you don't have to worry about getting rid of stale data.